# Add a new field to Create a course

Tags: php, moodle

im a new for PHP and Moodle 2.7.1+ ..., i want to add a field "Number of student" for control limited count of a course.

I did this in moodle\course\edit_form.php:

```
$mform->addElement('text','CountStudent', get_string('CountStudentcourse'),'maxlength="100"  size="10"');
        $mform->addHelpButton('CountStudent', 'CountStudentcourse');
        $mform->setType('CountStudent', PARAM_RAW);
        if (!empty($course->id) and !has_capability('moodle/course:changeCountStudent', $coursecontext)) {
            $mform->hardFreeze('CountStudent');
            $mform->setConstants('CountStudent', $course->CountStudent);
        }
```

In the view show: [[CountStudentcourse]] and HelpButton Error

have some simple example for fix all??
thanks for all helps!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something that should be part of an enrolment plugin, rather than directly part of course settings.

Is this supposed to be limiting self enrolments, manual enrolments, or both?

I would suggest either editing the code in enrol/manual or enrol/self (as appropriate) or creating a new enrolment plugin by copying the relevant one of these and renaming the references in the code to the original name.

You would then need to edit the file 'edit_form.php' to add the new setting. It is also possible to add enrolment plugin settings onto the course settings page (but I can't remember the function you have to define, off the top of my head).

You will need to carefully read through the code in the plugin you are creating, as there are quite a few places you'll need to change to get this fully working (too many to list easily here).

Comment: thanks for responde!! m... i did some change in file "edit_form.php" and added a field "CountStudent" in table "mdl_course". But i cant create a new course... said "Error writing to database":error/moodle/dmlwriteexception MySQL. Should I need add something more in the code??

Thanks!

Comment: Moodle doesn't work well with mixed-case fieldnames - the first thing you should do is rename the field to countstudent (although really, that data should be in an enrolment plugin, not in the main course table). Did you use the xmldb editor to create the field? https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor Have you also got debugging set to developer? https://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging

Comment: Hi! I went to: Site administration > Development > XMLDB editor but too many db... i dont know what is useful for create field in "Course"? Does not exist "mod/course/db". Do u know which db is it possible? Is "admin/tool/uploadcourse/db"?? Thanks

Comment: You create it inside your plugin - so, if you are creating an enrolment plugin (as advised) you should put the changes in there. Alternatively, you could create a 'local' plugin, and store the XMLDB changes inside that.